# How to keep color bar width consistent in seaborn heatmap subplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I am trying to plot two heat maps that have the same x-axis on a single figure with different subplots, the scales of each are different so they need different color bars. Each heatmap also has a different number of observations along the y-axis, see below:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

arr1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)*100
arr2 = np.random.rand(2, 10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, 
                     gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[5, 1]}, 
                     sharex=True)

sns.heatmap(arr1, ax=axes[0]) 
sns.heatmap(arr2, ax=axes[1])
```

[image]

The width of the color bars is not consistent between the plots. This makes sense and is not unexpected, however I would like to force the width of each to be consistent for aesthetic reasons.

I tried using the `cbar` parameter and explicitly defining the size and location of the colorbar:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, 
                     gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[5, 1]}, 
                     sharex=True)
sns.heatmap(arr1, ax=axes[0])

cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([.85, .135, .019, .15])
sns.heatmap(arr2, ax=axes[1], cbar_ax=cbar_ax)
```

[image]

Though in doing this the plots are no longer consistent width. Is the best approach here to define axes for each color bar on the individual axes subplots? It seems there may be a simpler way that I am missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution first

If possible, try using ***GridSpec*** to organize your 4 subplots (two main plots and two colorbars in their own `axes`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

arr1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)*100
arr2 = np.random.rand(2, 10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,
                         gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [5, 1], 
                                      'width_ratios': [30, 1], 
                                      'wspace': 0.1}, 
                         sharex='col')

sns.heatmap(arr1, ax=axes[0][0], cbar_ax=axes[0][1]) 
sns.heatmap(arr2, ax=axes[1][0], cbar_ax=axes[1][1])
```

[image]

## Then, some comments on your ideas:

When you use `add_axes`, you manually add a subplot (`axes`) and force it at a specific location. This might make it difficult for the new subplot to coordinate with other subplots. In your second plot, it turns out the 3rd `axes` floats around and sits on top of other subplots.

The problem with your second approach is that you move the colorbar out of the `axes` of `arr2`. Therefore, the main plot takes the full width of its `axes`, while the main plot of `arr1` shares the full width of its `axes` with its colorbar. Thought the two main plots seem to be "no longer consistent width", the two subplots (`axes` are still consistent in width).

Answer (score 3):

You can define the colorbar axes (`cbar_ax`) as part of the subplot grid, such that all the spacings and width are synchronized between the two rows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

arr1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)*100
arr2 = np.random.rand(2, 10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, 
                     gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[5, 1],
                                  'width_ratios' :[1, 0.04]})

sns.heatmap(arr1, ax=axes[0,0], cbar_ax=axes[0,1]) 
sns.heatmap(arr2, ax=axes[1,0], cbar_ax=axes[1,1]) 


plt.show()
```

[image]